# Maven Project Build Error : parent.relativePath points at no local POM

Tags: spring, maven, configuration

Searched throughout stackoverflow, found similar posts, but nothing specific to my issue, hence posting the question here.

Here is the error description:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.rahul.irs:rahulBoot_SpringCore:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find 
artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.10.RELEASE and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

And here is the snapshot of my pom.xml where I see the error:
[image]

[image]

I have replaced central repository to:

```
https://repo.spring.io/release/
```

Instead of:

```
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
```

Since my network is blocking default central repository.

Spring.io central repository is working in my network, however I'm getting the above error. Tried deleting local repositories, and tried Maven -> Update Project ->

[image]

But no luck. Can someone tell me whats going wrong here?

Comment: Please use text instead of images...

Comment: @khmarbaise
images are blocked at your end??

Comment: @Rahl Raj yes they are....

Comment: Please share you project structure

Answer (score 1):

**eclipse use the default maven settings.xml file from C:\Users\firstname.lastname.m2 Folder** .

```
Check Is setting.xml in  C:\Users\firstname.lastname\.m2 Folder exist or not.
```

If settings.xml file is not their just insert settings.xml.

```
mvn clean install spring-boot:run
```

You can get the settings.xml File inside the maven> conf folder e.g I extract maven zip in my d: drive  D:\ Drive with apache-maven-3.5.4 folder name so my settings.xml file  is in D:\apache-maven-3.5.4\conf