# Spring Boot 2.2.1 RELEASE build error-relative path

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-3

Am adding spring-boot parent in my `pom.xml` file as given below

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1 RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

i was change version version definition into `<properties>` tag as given below

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring-boot.version>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

after this change am getting build error

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for abc:abc:7.0.0.0: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:${spring-boot.version} in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 
 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

i tried following solutions

- `<relativePath/> to <relativePath>/<relativePath>`
- `<relativePath/> to <relativePath>../pom.xml/<relativePath>`
- `Updated maven project`

And also i tried following link
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808466/maven-project-build-error-parent-relativepath-points-at-no-local-pom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way not to inherit properties from a parent POM. Properties defined in a parent are visible in the child.